# Should I store the cognito auth token in my database?

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a mobile application which needs to be GDPR compliant. We're using AWS amplify and appsync, but we're unclear on how the Cognito auth token is used. Do we need to store the token in our database to associate it with users?

Our concern is that once a user is authenticated, the client will not know which userdata is associated with that identity unless we store the auth token.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store tokens. Cognito Auth token are JWT tokens. JWT tokens can have custom payload within them. Everything you need is already included in it. You can pass literally anything like userId, phoneNumber etc... any custom data when you are issuing the tokens.

For example, if you trigger lambda with apigateway and use cognito pools for authorization you will automatically get `sub` etc in the `claims` field which you will identify user in the client (in this case client is lambda)

If you are using custom lambda authorizers you can still use cognito user pools but this time you are absolutely free to embed any custom data into token to use it later.

Play in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) with your tokens and you will see whats in it already.

Comment: So I should be able to add a custom attribute to Cognito and attach a unique attribute to a user when they create their account, and store that attribute in our database as well.

So we know which user connected to the db is associated with the cognito user who logged in?

Comment: You dont need a custom attribute for that. You have to use `sub` value. Its GUID and unique identifier of users. Its available in lambda if you authorize apigateway with cognito for instance. Just use `sub` dont create your value

Comment: Thank you so much!